# Replacing new line character from Oracle to SQL Server migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, newline

I am trying to moving data from Oracle to SQL Server. Some columns have values with more than one line. The code is showing an error message when I try to insert records from Oracle into SQL Server. How to fix it?

```
Oracle                                          SQL Server

column name-> description                       column name-> description
Data type ->  varchar2(200)                     Data type -> nvarchar(400)
data      ->  sample values1
              sample values2
```

Comment: This should not be a problem if you link the databases to each other and use remote databases references to insert the data.  You are clearly doing something else, so the possible issues are pretty broad.

Comment: There is no `nvarchar2(n)` datatype in SQL Server .....

Comment: It will be difficult to provide a recommendation to fix it without seeing the code, Embedded new line characters and other whitespace shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sorry not nvarchar2.i am using nvarchar only I thought we have to replace the new line character when we insert records from oracle to sql server.will it insert in single line (sql server)without replacing new line character.

Comment: @Ram, whatever value is supplied will be inserted into the column. The value can contain many lines so the resultant value in SQL Server should be the same as in Oracle, except Unicode due to the nvarchar type.

Comment: Thank you.Now it is inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "replace" function, along with "chr(10)" (which is a carriage return) should do the trick.

If I have a table, say, mytable, that has a column "comments", and the "comments" column could have a carriage return in it. I could replace it with a "space character" as in the below:

For example:
select first_name, last_name, replace(comments, chr(10), ' ') from mytable;